# Is there a better way to write this code?

Tags: scala

I'm mainly thinking about testing the optional values and pulling out those values. Here's the code:

```
val optEmail: Option[String] = getOptionalEmailParam
val optPassword: Option[String] = getOptionalPasswordParam

if (optEmail.nonEmpty && optPassword.nonEmpty) {
  doSomething(optEmail.get, optPassword.get)
} else {
  doSomethingElse
}
```

I'd love something along the lines of

```
for (email <- optEmail; password <- optPassword) {
  doSomething(email, password)
} else {
  // Didn't get inside the for loop
  doSomethingElse
}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just turn your `for` loop into a `for/yield` (comprehension), and follow it up with `getOrElse`:

```
val a: Option[String] = Some("a")
val b: Option[String] = Some("b")
val n: Option[String] = None

(for(x <- a; y <- b) yield f"$x $y").getOrElse("else")  // "a b"
(for(x <- n; y <- b) yield f"$x $y").getOrElse("else")  // "else"
(for(x <- a; y <- n) yield f"$x $y").getOrElse("else")  // "else"
(for(x <- n; y <- n) yield f"$x $y").getOrElse("else")  // "else"
```

Monads!

So:

```
(for (email <- optEmail; password <- optPassword) yield {
  doSomething(email, password)
}).getOrElse(doSomethingElse)
```

Comment: Surely you mean Applicative functors! :) with a lack of suitable abstractions in Scala letting you express those cleanly without using more power than you need.

Comment: I ended up doing it this way

Answer (score 5):

I think a match statement looks nice and concise here:

```
val optEmail: Option[String] = getOptionalEmailParam
val optPassword: Option[String] = getOptionalPasswordParam

(optEmail, optPassword) match {
  case (Some(email),Some(password)) => doSomething(email, password)
  case _ => doSomethingElse
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this. I didn't think of matching on a tuple. I wish I could choose multiple correct solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that (it will return either doSomething or doSomethingElse)

```
(
  for {
    email <- optEmail if email.nonEmpty
    pw  <- optPassword if pw.nonEmpty
  } yield doSomething(email,pw) 
) getOrElse doSomethingElse
```

Comment: The conditionals are unnecessary b/c monad

Comment: conditionals are for what's inside monad (so Some("") won't pass, but Some("dfdf") will)

Answer (score 1):

you can also do something like this to auto-encrypt your code

```
   optEmail.fold(doSomethingElse)(
     email => optPassword.fold(doSomethingElse)
       (pw => doSomething(email,pw)))
```

or

```
 (optEmail zip optPassword).
   headOption.fold(doSomethingElse)(p => doSomething(p._1,p._2))
```